# self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow does not work with accessory and why..?

Tags: ios, objective-c

basically when i click accessory button on the cell, if i try to access the indexPath by doing indexPathForSelectedRow, then it doesn't work properly returning **nil**. so i researched and found i need to use indexPathForCell:sender inside prepareForseGue:sender method. so..why..?

I found that i need to use this code in prepareForsegue:sender: working with **accessory**

```
[self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]
```

But, I haven't found why

```
self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow
```

this code doesn't work and why it is giving **nil** when it comes to dealing with accessory..?

could you explain "why"...?

Comment: Can you be more clear on what your problem is and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You need to provide more context. Where is the code that is causing you the problem?

Comment: basically when i click accessory button on the cell, if i try to access the indexPath by doing indexPathForSelectedRow, then it doesn't work properly. so i researched and found i need to use indexPathForCell:sender inside prepareForseGue:sender method. so..why..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `accessory` view (On the right edge of the cell) does not `select` the cell. Therefore, when tapping an accessory, selected cell will be nil.
You can see that when selecting a cell by default it gets gray (on iOS7, blue on earlier versions), while when clicking the accessory view on the cell it won't.

Depends on what you try to achieve, you can force the cell to be selected when tapping the accessory button - one way can be to chain the button to action instead of segue, than on that action call `selectRowAtIndexPath:` and than explicitly call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` (Just as a side note - selecting a row in code will **not** call the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`)